# Django. Не импортируется bboard

Tags: python, django

Делал все по учебнику, но почему-то в urls.py не импортируется `bboard.views`.

В учебнике написано так:

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from bboard.views inport index
    urlpatterns = [
        path(’bboard/’, index),
        path(’admin/’, admin.site.urIs),
    ]
```

Перед этим я через консоль создал папку bboard, и в views все настроил. Но все равно ничего не выходит.

В чём проблема и что делать?

Comment: Опечатка не `inport`, а `import`

Comment: Да даже если правильно писать, все равно тот же рузельтат. Питон даже from bboard не видит почему то.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что `bboard` - это приложение, поскольку вы используете `views`  в импорте. Если это так, то не достаточно просто создать папку и положить в нее файл.

Первое, для создания приложения существует функциональность в `django`

```
...\> py manage.py startapp bboard
```

После выполнения команды, у вас как результат будет новая папка `bboard`, которая будет содержать `admin.py`, `apps.py`, `models.py`, `test.py`, `views.py`.

Второе, для корректной работы, данное приложение необходимо зарегестрировать в `settings.py` проекта, то есть необходимо добавить строку в

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bboard.apps.BboardConfig',
    ....
]
```

И должно все получиться.